# Java collection framework hierarchy diagram?

Tags: java, collections

I am learning Java Collection Framework, and got the basics of this framework.

Is there any reliable / official Collection framework hierarchy diagram for ease of reference? I referred online, many of the diagrams are outdated and can't rely on the search results.

Can anyone let me know if we have any reliable diagram which represents the hierarchy of Collection Framework (say, till Java 1.8).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: @GregArtisi: I am looking more of diagram for ease of reference :-)

Comment: Check this: http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/overview-of-java-collections-framework-api-uml-diagram

Comment: @Ivan: Thanks, but they don't seem to be depiciting the correct hierarchy. Thanks for your help,

Comment: https://infinitescript.com/2014/10/java-collections-framework/

Answer (score 5):

__________ : extends

-----------: implements
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Every Class and Interface have some version number i.e version in which these classes or interfaces are introduced. They are specified below name of Class or Interface(i.e 1.2,1.3)
2. Legacy classes means it is available from the first version of java.
3. (I)->Interface,(C)->Class

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBcwr.png) 
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d660p.png)